# Как создать слайд, который показывает скрытые кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть список кнопок, часть которых является скрытыми.

Нужно создать слайд, который при нажатии на кнопку "следующий" переключился на следующую кнопку, а если она скрытая, то показывал эту скрытую кнопку, при переключении на следующую скрытую кнопку предыдущая должна скрыться, а текущая должна появиться.

Во время переключения на скрытые кнопки основные кнопки должны сохранять своё состояние.

**HTML**

```
// Cписок с кнопками 
<ul>
    <li class="slide visible"><button class="btn"/>Button Visible One</li> 
    <li class="slide visible"><button class="btn"/>Button Visible Two</li> 
    <li class="slide hidden"><button class="btn"/>Button Hidden One</li> 
    <li class="slide hidden"><button class="btn"/>Button Hidden Two</li>
</ul> 

// Кнопки для передвижения 
<button id="previous">Previos</button>  
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden { display: none; } 
.visible { display: block; }
```

Comment: Какую часть задачи вы сделали, с чем возникли затрудения? Покажите код, который у вас есть к текущему моменту.

Comment: Код просто очень большой поэтому решил максимально точно сформировать свою просьбу. 
Ладно, у меня есть список в нём 4 кнопки, первые две имеют класс "видимый", а те класс "скрытый". У меня так же есть кнопки вперёд и назад, которые перебирают этот список. Мне нужно, чтобы когда я листаю вперёд и дохожу к 3 кнопке, т.е. к первой скрытой кнопке, она стала видимым, а когда перехожу к 4 скрытой кнопке, тогда третья скрывается, а 4 становится видимым. Независимо от всего первые две кнопки должны всегда быть видимыми и на своих места. 
Был бы очень благодарен, если бы Вы помогли.

Comment: HTML
// Cписок с кнопками
 <ul><li class="slide visible"><button class="btn"/>Button Visible One</li>
 <li class="slide visible"><button class="btn"/>Button Visible Two</li>
 <li class="slide hidden"><button class="btn"/>Button Hidden One</li>
 <li class="slide hidden"><button class="btn"/>Button Hidden Two</li></ul>

// Кнопки для передвижения
<button id="previous">Previos</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>

CSS .
hidden { display: none; } .visible { display: block; }

JS

Comment: Добавьте код с html и js в вопрос. В комментарии код читать очень сложно. Кнопка **править** под вопросом.

Comment: Добавил изменения.